# SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 3. Illegal combination of non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to upload .csv through Informatica but its getting failed with below error.

I have tried to check with all this fields combination but still getting this error.

SQL*Loader: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Jan 15 13:08:32 2024
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 3.
Illegal combination of non-alphanumeric characters
AR(4000) ,DECLINED CHAR(4000) ,NTU CHAR(4000) ,100_PERCENT_PREMIUM,NOT

I want this fields should get imported correctly.

Comment: Please make your issue reproducible by providing the SQL statement / input data that makes the query fail.

Comment: I have created the table as mentioned below  CREATE TABLE DUMMY
   ( "PLACEMENT_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
 "ROW_NUMBER" NUMBER(38,0), 
 "MARKET" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
 "DECLINED" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
 "NTU" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
 "100_PERCENT_PREMIUM" FLOAT(126), 
 "NOTES" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
 "UNDERWRITER_NAME" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
 "EXECUTION_TIME" DATE)

Comment: I don't know Informatica, but I did load quite a few data via SQL Loader. If possible, provide control file and sample input data so that we could try to reproduce loading session.

Comment: Its working fine while inserting the data directly though Import data but failing when processign it with ETL tool.This is sample data  PLACEMENT_ID ROW_NUMBER MARKET DECLINED NTU 100_PERCENT_PREMIUM NOTES UNDERWRITER_NAME EXECUTION_TIME
2050FebKK Repdo 1 Homemaker  Terms and Conditions  100 Offered jgmjvmj KK 30-Nov-23
2050FebKK Repdo 2 Travelers Engineering  7.89 dummy food JK 30-Nov-23